# Slow down playing song without reloading mixer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm looking in learning how to use pygame, and with that experimenting with stuff and making a little test game.

Now, I haven't found an answer for something. I want to have a music (`pygame.mixer.music`) and perhaps sounds (`pygame.mixer.Sound`) play normally, but when asked, change to a specific frequency. At this point all I've found is to do `pygame.mixer.init(frequency=9000)` and when required, call `pygame.mixer.quit()` then `pygame.mixer.init(frequency=9001)` which is what I want to avoid, as I would like to have it play without the song cutting down, sound like it never stopped and it be on same point it was on. I'm not sure if it's possible or not in pygame, hence me asking. If it isn't I am open to recommendations for libraries that do.

**EDIT**: In case of mentioning a lib that can do this, I'd prefer it to support OGG. Although would be nice if it could be done in pygame.

Comment: You need to dynamically re-sample so to slow by half you need to transform from X samples per second to 2X samples and then have the audio device consume them at X samples per second. I don't think `pygame.mixer` supports playing the result of a re-sampled transformed stream.

Comment: @DanD. what could I do/use then?

Comment: Try [vlc](https://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=history;f=generated/vlc.py;). You'll have to search a lot on the documentation though. And I do not know if it is possible to achieve what you want, with vlc.

Comment: I haven't personally used it but pygame has a [`sndarray`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sndarray.html) which turns sounds to an numpy array. You can then create and apply functions on the matrix to get a new sound array which you convert back to a sound object. It requires some knowledge about sound theory and matrix operations and can potentially be a slow operations for longer sounds or music.

Comment: Btw, your title say "slow down" the song while the question is about changing frequency. Changing the speed of a song is quite easy and it does change the pitch as well, but is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.mixer`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html) does not support playing the result of a resampled transformed stream. You must resample dynamically. To reduce the speed by half, you must transform from X samples per second to 2X samples, and then make the audio device play them at X samples per second.